# "Stick" imported files to a grid - three.js

Tags: javascript, file, stl, three.js

I'm working in an .Stl editor on Three.js and i wonder how to "stick" the imported .Stl files to the grid, so they can't be half'top/half down the grid or even floating over or under. I need something to check if the lowest part of my object is touching the grid or something like that.

The problem is the only position I can get from my files is the origin of them , one little point usually in the center of them but not always so if I place it to Y = 0 - the grid y position -sometimes a part is at a lower position (and i got rotation and resizing option) .

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center the geometry of your stl model.

```
geometry.center();
```

and then you can stick it with its top to the grid

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
geometry.translate(0, -geometry.boundingBox.max.y, 0 );
```

or with its bottom

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
geometry.translate(0, -geometry.boundingBox.min.y, 0 );
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/mcrm8jox/) example. The gray model there is at original position.

Comment: Thanks this is a great help but it only work on the loading of the File. Whenever i apply a rotation (and call my function), the sticking doesnt work.

Comment: there's no problem to assign your model to a global variable and operate with it. I've updated the fiddle.